# How to overcome Xcode: 'Write permission error'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, apple-developer

When trying to delete certificates in Xcode, there is a dialogue pop-up that says `Write permission error`

[image]

[image: me]

I am looking to delete these old certificates to add new ones. It seems they must be deleted in order to use the new certificates that were generated. Is it possible to delete these?

Comment: you can find these certificates in keychain and delete it directly

Comment: Ty for the reply! Yep. The weird thing is I did several times. They are currently still shown in Xcode. They are currently nonexistent in the key chain and in my in my online account at the moment.

Comment: Even tried deleting the entire derived data folder.

Comment: Might try reinstalling Xcode but don't want to get locked out. This happened on my iPad mini running iOS 9.3.5 after deleting instagram; got a 'This device doesn't support IG' pop up type of thing...haha

Comment: I'm in the same situation, did you solve it?

Comment: deleting the certificate directly in the keychain worked for my team